# beforeunload in Microsoft Edge not firing

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, onbeforeunload

I have `beforeunload` added in my js code as follows and it works in IE10
I would like to give the user a warning, nothing else

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    init();
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {

        if (changeSubmitted) {          
            return 'If you choose to leave, the data entered will not be saved!';

        }
        return true;

    });
});
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/dergerntod/pen/brwmWd)

However, the event doesn't seem to fire in Edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately all major browsers removed support for the custom message in `onbeforeunload` event, now they just show their own generic text. Except of IE :)

Take a look at [browser compatibility list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility).